# Create SQL from parameters including FROM clause

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Is it possible to create a stored procedure that calls a SQL statement with a parameter in the select statement and another in the FROM clause?

It sees to me that is not possible, but I don't know much about pl/sql.

The code below is not working of course. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1 table1 VARCHAR(100)
                                       field1 VARCHAR(100)
IS
BEGIN
    FOR I IN (SELECT field1
                FROM TABLE (table1)
               WHERE field1 IS NOT NULL)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Field_name : ' || I.FIELD_NAME);
    END LOOP;
END procedure1;
```

Comment: Yes it is possible with dynamic SQL but you expose yourself to SQL Injection attacks

Comment: By the way, tables have columns not fields.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can construct the SQL in a variable and execute it. It should work.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CRAZY_PROC (tableName    VARCHAR2,
                                        fieldName    VARCHAR2)
AS
    sqlString   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
    sqlString := 'select ' || fieldName || ' from ' || tableName;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sqlString);
END;
/
```